# Resume an app from the page last viewed in windows store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am new to Windows Store apps. I have developed an app in c#/xaml having different pages. When a user closes(and not suspends) an app and restarts it next time, I want that the same page should appear which he last viewed before closing the app.

Please tell me an easy way to do this. Do I need to change the entry point in the manifest along with some code..

Please tell in a little detail as I am new.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx), then [continue here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx).
There is a lot documentation about your problem.